# Change State whenever button is clicked back and forth in React?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, state

So I know how to change state when the button is clicked once, but how would I change the new state back to the previous state when the button is clicked again?

Answer (score 7):

You can just toggle the state.

Here's an example using a Component:

```
class ButtonExample extends React.Component {
  state = { status: false }

  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ status: !status })}>
        {`Current status: ${status ? 'on' : 'off'}`}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an example using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (available in v16.8.0):

```
const ButtonExample = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setStatus(!status)}>
      {`Current status: ${status ? 'on' : 'off'}`}
    </button>
  );
};
```

You can change the `'on'` and `'off'` to anything you want to toggle. Hope this helps!

Comment: This only toggles a single value. What if the compoent has two complex states, each with a timestamp of when that state was created?

Comment: True, but that didn't seem to be the intention of the question. If Eduardo wanted to know how to do something more complicated I figured he would have provided more detail in his question.

Comment: _"How would I change the new state back to the previous state"_. That's not the same as _"how do I toggle a boolean value"_...

Comment: You seem upset. The question is two sentences, and discusses a button (which generally has two states). I answered the question based on what I believed Eduardo was asking. If he doesn't like the answer I provided, he won't accept my answer.

Comment: I assure you that my mood is never affected by a conversation on SO. I assume that programmers learn how to flip a boolean their first day of programming. Reverting state is s much different problem, and it happens to be exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example of show on toggle by using React Hook without using useCallback().

When you click the button, it shows "Hello" and vise-versa.

Hope it helps.

```
const IsHiddenToggle = () => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false);

  return (
      <button onClick={() => setIsHidden(!isHidden)}>
      </button>
      {isHidden && <p>Hello</p>}
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/mkv8heu6/6/

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     buttonState: true
    }
    this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h2>Button Toggle: {this.state.buttonState.toString()}</h2>                
        <button onClick={this.toggleState}>Toggle State</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  toggleState() {
   this.setState({ buttonState: !this.state.buttonState })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here we use a boolean true/false and flip between the two states.  If you are looking to use some other custom data as your previous state, just create a different variable for that.

For example:

```
this.state = { previousValue: "test", currentValue: "new thing" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will toggle to previous and new value :

```
 constructor() {
        super();

      this.state = {
        inputValue: "0"
      }
    }

     render() {
     return (
     <div>
      <input
        type="button"
        name="someName"
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        onClick={() =>
         this.state.inputValue === "0"
         ? this.setState({
         inputValue: "1"
         })
         : 
        this.setState({
        inputValue: "0"
        })
        }
         className="btn btn-success"
      />
    </div>
     )
    }
```

Description :

If the current value = 0, then set the value to 1, and vice versa.

This is useful if you have a lot of inputs. So, each input has a different state or condition.

Answer (score 0):

You must save the previous state. You could even make previous state part of your actual state - but I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP (Note: you could preserve a full history of previous states using that technique). Unfortunately I cannot yet write examples from the top of my head using the new hooks feature:

```
class MyComponent extends ReactComponent {
  prevState = {}
  state = {
    isActive: false,
    // other state here
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    // should probably use deep clone here
    const state = Object.assign({}, this.state);

    this.setState(state.isActive ? this.prevState : Object.assign(state, { 
      isActive: true,
      // other state here
    });

    this.prevState = state;
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Toggle State</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: This may work in a simple example but is not a good idea.  `setState` can take a function instead of an object, which allows you to access previous state (see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).  Also, you do not want to copy your entire state and apply that to set state.  That's overkill.  You just supply the object that you want to change.  React will retain all unchanged state.

Comment: @larz actually, you don't get the previous state in the callback - you get the current state... which will soon become the previous state once a new state is created.

Comment: Also, copying the entire state and passing it to `setState` is a common pattern (read about immutability with React). React's diffing algorithm is extremely fast and can pick up on the pieces that changed.

Answer (score 0):

in state:

```
this.state = {toggleBtn: ""}
```

in your button:

```
<button key="btn1" onClick={() => this.clickhandler(btn1)}>
   {this.state.toggleBtn === ID? "-" : "+"}
</button>
```

in your clickhandler:

```
clickhandler(ID) {

if (this.state.toggleBtn === ID) {
        this.setState({ toggleBtn: "" });
    } else {
        this.setState({ toggleBtn: ID});
    }
```